# How to prevent server from crashes due to number of tasks in celery queue

Tags: django, python-2.7, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have one queue, i am calling 50 tasks per second continuously in this queue, queue takes 1 second to execute one task
. Now the other tasks are in pending/waiting state, so it consumes the server memory 
and **after 2 hour, the server/rabitmq crashes.**

So is there any way to put the limit on pending task, or can i remove pending task after some time limit?

Here my celery configuration setting:

```
app = Celery('uhr', backend='amqp',     
broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//')

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json', 'pickle'],  
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_TIMEZONE='Europe/Madrid', 
    CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True,
    # CELERYD_NODES=3,
    # CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 2,
    CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True,
    CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1,
    CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True,
    CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1,
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 1800,
    CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 1200,
    CELERY_ROUTES={
        'myproject.tasks.testqueue':{'queue':'myqueue'},

    }
)
```

I want to prevent my server/rabitmq from crash. Is there any way?

Comment: Probably you should add workers for quicker empting the queue. How many workers you have?

Comment: Yes,You are right, I know this. I have one worker right now. Though i want to make sure to prevent server
from crash. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should look at towards to settings of rabbitmq Did you read an article https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html ?